# Maximum Row in DBMS

Tags: mysql, database, row, tuples, max

Is there any limit to maximum row of table in DBMS (specially MySQL)?

I want create table for saving logfile and it's row increase so fast I want know what shoud I do to prevent any problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should periodically move log rows out to a historical database for data mining and purge them from the transactional database.  It's a common practice.

Comment: Tanx, it's a practical solution.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is an official limit, it will depend on maximum index sizes and filesystem restrictions.

From [mySQL 5.0 Features](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/features.html):

> Support for large databases. We use MySQL Server with databases that contain 50 million records. We also know of users who use MySQL Server with 200,000 tables and about 5,000,000,000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably some sort of limitation, dependent on the engine used and the table structure. I've got a table with appx 45 million entries in a database I administrate, I've heard of (much) higher numbers.