# Mysql no. of data

Tags: mysql

Does mysql have any datarows limit.
I mean there's gotta be a limit somewhere, or maybe just a limit for a user.

Anyone knows if there is a limit for a user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximum Row in DBMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822522/maximum-row-in-dbms)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a limit (Actually there are a few).

1. The file size of your filesystem.  Since MySQL (all engines) stores the table in a maximum of 1 file (InnoDB can store multiple tables in one file), the filesystem's file size limit will be restrictive of how many rows you can have.  Now, if you're using a modern filesystem, it won't be too bad.  See this list for more information: [Comparison of filesystem limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits).
2. The row pointer in the storage engine (MyISAM for instance is 6 bytes by default, 7 bytes max).  Granted, these numbers are huge (256TB default, 65,536TB max for MyISAM), but they are there.
3. Data type of your primary key.  If you use `INT`, you're capped at 2.1 billion rows (4.3 if you used unsigned).  If you used a `BIGINT`, you're capped at 9.2x10^18 rows (18.4x10^18 if unsigned).  Of course this doesn't apply to tables without an auto-incremeneted PK.
4. InnoDB's maximum tablespace size is 64TB, so that's the max table size in Inno.
5. There may be more, but that's what I can think of...

Check out [this documentation page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/full-table.html) for more information...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no row limit as such, and there definitely is no per-user limit - it would not make sense in a database system.

See [E.7. Limits in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limits.html) in the manual and the duplicate link I posted.